# Running a background ruby script from a php page

Tags: php, ruby

So I have two ruby scripts that scrape two websites for information based on what it entered via a form.  Basically, the form outputs to a file, and the two ruby scripts take their input from that file and proceed to scrape and return a viewable html file. My problem is that I have no idea how to connect the php file to the ruby scripts.  When I was writing them, I just tested them via the terminal to ensure they worked correctly.  Now that I have everything done, I am lost when it comes how to actually execute the scripts from the php file that writes the user input to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a poller in the ruby script that checks the file you write from PHP periodically. There is an issue of concurrency when you are trying to do this: the producer could be writing at the same time the consumer is reading.

I suggest to read and write to DB, so you don't have to worry about it. If you don't want to setup a fully professional DB, you can use SQLite ([ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby) [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)).

Comment: So, I would write the user input to the database, and then the script would check the database for its input and then display that?  I am beginning to think I just approached this entire situation in the worst way possible and wasted my time writing it in ruby.  I thought it would be easy to just have two scripts that get run every time a user accessed the page and then it would create the output.  I never even considered multiple users at the same time.  Ugh, I should have planned this much better.

Comment: That depends on how much you have to scrape and if you want to decouple that work from page loading. I would do that. Probably would use Rails + Sidekiq + Mechanize to do this in Ruby, they are much more powerful.

Comment: Guess I better start learning rails.

Comment: I think it really depends on how far you want to go with scraping. Ever heard of import.io? Maybe you can use their API from the PHP script.

Comment: Well I am basically taking a table from each of two sites and then I just want to display those two tables.